# ASP.NET Core MVC : default view & route

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC router question.

When I change index route to `[Route("Index")]` in `HomeController` [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlbWR.png), and then enter the url `localhost:5000/index` in web browser, it works!

But in my ASP.NET Core MVC project, the default startup url is `localhost:5000/home/index` [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWpy8.png).

**Question**

How can I change the default startup url to `localhost:5000/index`?

I wish use `localhost:5000/home/login` to visit the login function in the `HomeController`.

Comment: Describe more details what do you mean **_how can I change default startup to "localhost:5000/index"?_**, please. Is your requirement the `localhost:5000/index` should be displayed when user entering the `localhost:5000`?

Answer (score 1):

Add following route before your default route.

```
 endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "customindex",
    pattern: "index",
    defaults: new { controller="Home", action="Index"});
            });
```

pattern can support default value but it works with common scenario like controller/action but if you want specific pattern then you have to specify pattern and also set defaults so those will supply as route value in order to identify action to call.